# how to support only specific platform versions in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

i try to develop specific application using xamarin forms but i want to support specific platforms versions like android v6+ and IOS 10.
How to make that ? is there any customization control to make this ? or any options ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure this in your [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/) and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/compiling_for_different_devices/#SDK_Options) platform projects, not your shared Forms project.